# Java file imports

Tags: java

Can anyone assist me in figuring out why the following code always throws the catch for the file not being found. the input.txt file is in the same folder as the class and I cant seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FileAssignment extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTextArea tField;
JButton send;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileAssignment frame = new FileAssignment();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public FileAssignment() {

    GridBagConstraints layout;

    Font tFont = new Font("Arial", + Font.ITALIC, 16);
    Font bFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 18);

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    layout = new GridBagConstraints();
    layout.gridx = 0;
    layout.gridy = 0;
    layout.insets = new Insets(10, 50, 10, 50);

    layout= new GridBagConstraints();
    layout.gridx = 0;
    layout.gridy = 1;
    layout.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    tField = new JTextArea();
    tField.setEditable(false);

    send = new JButton("Show minimum wage employees");
    send.addActionListener(this);       

    add(tField, layout);
    add(send, layout);
    send.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);

    tField.setFont(tFont);
    send.setFont(bFont);

    setTitle("Employee Wages");

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    try {

        double p1 = 9999.99;
        double price;
        String name;

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

        while (scnr.hasNext()) {

            name = scnr.nextLine();
            price = Double.parseDouble(scnr.nextLine());

            if (price < p1) {

                p1 = price;

            }

        }

        scnr.close();

        scnr = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

        while (scnr.hasNext()) {

            name = scnr.nextLine();
            price = Double.parseDouble(scnr.nextLine());

            if (price == p1) {

                p1 = price;
                tField.append( name + "\n");

            }

        }

        scnr.close();

    } 

    catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println("File read error");

    }

}

}
```

Sorry about some of the weird spacing.

Comment: **How** are you running this?

Comment: *"the input.txt file is in the same folder as the class"* - That's probably you first problem. If you want to access the file as a "standard file", the the file should reside in the same location that java was run from (aka "the woking directory").  Otherwise you can treat it as an embedded resource, in which case you can keep it where it is, but the process of reading it changes

Comment: Eclipse. Sorry. I'm new to asking here.

Comment: The error say's it all. The file isn't being found.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. I had it in the wrong folder. How do I mark as solved?

Comment: The best thing would be to delete the question.